# c program crashes when a function prints the contents of array of pointers

Tags: c, function, crash

I am learning C. I wrote my program to read the data from a text file and print it out. During the building process compiler did not give errors. However, the program crashed when I tried to run it. I checked that when `printTable` function is removed, the program runs and prints the contents in the loop in `main()`. I also tried to remove variable "`total`" but the program still crashed. What is the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
char *country;
int females;
int males;
}person_count;

void printTable(person_count *data[]){
    printf("Country  Females  Males  Total\n");
    int i;
    int total[158];
    for(i=0;i<158;i++){

        total[i]=data[i]->females+data[i]->males;

        printf("%15s  %7i  %7i  %8i\n",data[i]->country,data[i]->females,data[i]->males,total[i]);
    }
}


int main(){
    person_count *data[158];

    FILE *eduData=fopen("SecondaryEd2005.txt","r");
    if(eduData==NULL){
        printf("File not found.");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("File opened successfully.\n");

    int k;
    for(k=0;k<158;k++){
        data[k]=malloc(sizeof(person_count));
        char place[20];
        fscanf(eduData,"%s %i %i\n",place,&data[k]->females,&data[k]->males);
        data[k]->country=place;
        printf("%s %i %i\n",data[k]->country,data[k]->females,data[k]->males);
    }

    printTable(data);

    fclose(eduData);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample of txt file contents:

Belgium 391138  423401
Belize  15591   15786
Benin   154266  281183
Bermuda 2494    2262
Bhutan  19870   22274

Comment: `data[k]->country=place` - that buffer is used again for the next entry (and the next, etc.), left dangling each time as `place[]` is lost once the for-loop scope is reached on each iteration.

Comment: Are any of the countries in your input file longer than 19 characters?

Comment: Yes, there are indeed countries with size 25 or so. Thank you, I changed the size of place[] to 30 and the program runs. However, printTable prints only one country - the last one in the file. I think WhozCraig stated sth about that. How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your person_count struct :

```
typedef struct{
    char country[20];
    int females;
    int males;
}person_count;
```

The line `data[k]->country=place;` should be replaced by `memcpy(data[k]->country, place, 20*sizeof(char));`

WhozCraig gave you the answer in his comment. Your code copy a pointer which is lost at next loop iteration.

Be aware that this code will work only if all your countries are less than 19 characters. You could also stick to the char* pointer, but in that case you will have to allocate memory and free it after usage.

Comment: Thanks, Nicolas. I changed the "country" to array type and applied changes suggested by Mike. Now the program works well. The only question is why some output entries look like:  "British_Virgin_Islanь     1020      862      1882" (country entries include some strange symbols and squares) ?

Comment: Since you are storing letters in char there's only 8 bits which makes 255 possibilities. If your text file contains special characters they are probably using 2 bytes and they will appears as 2 characters. You should learn about ascii and utf-8 if you want to handle special characters.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your program for you. The most important thing is to make country a fixed length array of chars, not a pointer. Also, make sure you free all memory you allocate to your program or you'll generate memory leaks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
  char country[20]; //fixed to reflect country field better
  int females;
  int males;
}person_count;

void printTable(person_count *data[],int items){
  items++;
  int i,total[items]; //replaced fixed value with variable to prevent excessive empty rows from printing
  printf("Country  Females  Males  Total\n");
  for(i=0;i<items;i++){
  total[i]=data[i]->females+data[i]->males;
  printf("%15s  %7i  %7i  %8i\n",data[i]->country,data[i]->females,data[i]->males,total[i]);
  }
}


int main(){

  FILE *eduData=fopen("SecondaryEd2005.txt","r");
  if(eduData==NULL){
  printf("File not found.");
  exit(1);
  }
  printf("File opened successfully.\n");

  int k,fscanret;
  person_count* data[159]; //added 1 to prevent out of bounds memory access

  for(k=0;k<158;k++){
data[k]=malloc(sizeof(person_count));
fscanret=fscanf(eduData,"%s %i %i\n",data[k]->country,&data[k]->females,&data[k]->males);
if (fscanret==EOF){ //check return value to avoid going past end of file
  free(data[k]); //discard empty record and free memory if EOF reached
  k--;
  break;
}
printf("%s %i %i\n",data[k]->country,data[k]->females,data[k]->males);
  }
  fclose(eduData);

  printTable(data,k); //print k number of entries.

  while (k>=0){
free(data[k]); //free memory for all entries. DONT FORGET THIS
k--;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to use *country pointer because in the task it is stated to that it should be a pointer?

Comment: If you're going to use it as a pointer, then you'll need to set it to point to either a fixed global char array or a pointer to allocated memory. In either event, I think by declaring country as a pointer, it will require the processor to do more work to get the job done.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to make the changes suggested by you and others- freeing memory, changing "country" to array typeand other things. Now the program works fully. ButI think I will try country pointer just to check.